Custom memory allocator with unique pool tag
I'm developing a driver for Windows in kernel space and am working on implementing a custom memory allocator that adheres to the constraints of kernel development, such as the prohibition of using modern C++ libraries (like type traits, memory, etc.). However, I can use some C++17 syntax features like constexpr. The goal is to have the memory allocator apply to every class in a way that each class (and derived classes) have their own memory pool tag for allocation. Specifically, if class A derives from class B, both A and B should have unique pool tags.
Here's what I've tried:
class KernelAllocator
{
public:
    KernelAllocator(ULONG tag) : m_tag(tag) {}

    void* allocate(size_t size, POOL_TYPE poolType = NonPagedPool) const
    {
        return AllocateMemory(size, poolType, m_tag);
    }

    void deallocate(void* p) const
    {
        DeAllocateMemory(p, m_tag);
    }

private:
    ULONG m_tag;
};

template <typename T, ULONG Tag>
class MemAllocator
{
public:
    static void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        return Allocator.allocate(size, NonPagedPool);
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        Allocator.deallocate(p);
    }

    static KernelAllocator Allocator;
};

template <typename T, ULONG Tag>
KernelAllocator MemAllocator<T, Tag>::Allocator(Tag);

Usage example:
class ClassA : public MemAllocator<ClassA, MEM_POOL_TAG_A> { ... };
auto classA = new ClassA();  // Works fine with unique pool tag

However, I run into a problem with inheritance:
class ClassB : public ClassA { ... };

The compiler throws an exception due to the ambiguity of the new operator implementation. I considered implementing MemAllocator only for the base class and then just replacing the pool tag, but this requires different handling for the base class and its children. I'm seeking a generic mechanism that can be applied across all classes I intend to use in my code.
How can I design a memory allocator that allows for unique memory pool tags in a class hierarchy while avoiding issues with operator ambiguity in derived classes? Is there a pattern or design approach suitable for kernel space development that adheres to these constraints?
